# Django redirect is not working with dropzone.js

Tags: django, redirect, dropzone

Redirect in Django is not working when files are uploaded using `Dropzone.js`, so I used `windows.href` in the Dropzone `success` event but I have to pass a parameter.

**views.py:**

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['files']:
    ...
    if form.is_valid():
        ....
        user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        id = user.id
        return redirect(reverse('success', kwargs={'id': id})) <<-- not working
```

**JQuery - Dropzone:**

```
this.on('success', function() {
    window.location.href = '/success/';
})
```

I don't reckon there is a way to pass the `id` to JQuery in this case, so I have to use redirect in Django. How can it get done?

Comment: Is this works `window.location.href = '/success/';`?

Comment: Yes it works in the original case, but how can I pass a parameter to '/success/id='?

Comment: @elle you need to get a parameter  in `success` function of dropzone  something like this: `this.on('success', function(data) {window.location.href = '/success/?id='+data['id'];})`

Comment: do you have any url `/sucess/<id>`

Comment: Yes, that part is okay but how can I pass it to JQuery from Django as I can't use 'return'?

Comment: @elle with `return JsonResponse({'id':id})` check it out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

Comment: why can't you use return ?

Comment: Somehow, now the return works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why django redirect is not working is because dropzone.js uses AJAX for its post requests which doesn't redirect pages.

To get the redirect to work you need to get the dropzone to redirect with javascript to the correct url given as a response from the POST request. The view returns a JSON response that then can be parsed from the js. This is done as follows:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def index(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BenchmarkForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():

            model_id = YourModel.objects.create(file=request.FILES['file']).id

            link = reverse('energy:benchmark',kwargs={'id':model_id})

            response = {'url':link} 

            return JsonResponse(response)
```

Then in the dropzone init function you need to parse the response in the success callback.

```
 Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {

                // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
                autoProcessQueue : false,
                url: "{% url 'energy:index' %}",

                headers: {
                     "X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"
                },

                init : function() {
                    mydropzone = this;

                    this.on("success", function(file, response) {
                        window.location.href=JSON.parse(file.xhr.response).url
                    });
```